# Dash mechanic not working as intended (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code right now, I call it elsewhere. It currently makes me float in place (I can still move normally while floating) and then drops me, nowhere does it apply the movement on the X that is desired, can anyone help? Cheers!

```
 private IEnumerator Dash()
    {
        if (!canDash)
            yield break;
 
        canDash = false;
        isDashing = true;
 
        float originalGravity = playerBody.gravityScale;
        playerBody.gravityScale = 0f;
 
        // Store the current velocity
        float originalVelocityX = playerBody.velocity.x;
        float originalVelocityY = playerBody.velocity.y;
 
        // Apply the dash velocity
        playerBody.velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x * dashSpeed, 0f);
 
        // Wait for the dash time
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashTime);
 
        // Restore the original horizontal velocity
        playerBody.velocity = new Vector2(originalVelocityX, originalVelocityY);
 
        // Wait for the dash cooldown
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashCooldown);
 
        isDashing = false;
        canDash = true;
        playerBody.gravityScale = originalGravity;
    }
```

I tried changing the transform.localScale.x to transform.position.x with a similar result.

I ideally want a quick movement on the x axis (whichever way the player is running), but instead have pause in y, while being able to walk along x and then being dropped back to the ground.

Also dashCooldown does not seem to have any impact.

Using unity's new input manager, the dash is binded to Q and that bit works.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from just this snippet, but a couple potential issues come to mind.

Firstly, you are only setting the velocity on a single frame, and it's hard to say how the velocity is being affected by other things like the movement you are still able to do. As it says in the docs:
["In most cases you should not modify the velocity directly, as this can result in unrealistic behaviour - use AddForce instead"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

A more reliable technique would be to apply forces, rather than completely overriding the velocity. If you are setting the velocity in a similar way anywhere else, that could definitely be an issue. It sounds like what you want in this case is a sudden impulse force. Try replacing:

```
playerBody.velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x * dashSpeed, 0f);
```

with something like:

```
playerBody.AddForce(transform.localPosition.forward * dashSpeed,
ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Could also give ForceMode.VelocityChange a shot, see what works well for you.

It could also just be that the velocity that you are trying to apply is really weak and not causing much change. transform.localscale is a strange metric to use for scaling the dash speed. It could work if you want the dash speed to scale with the size of the player, but if not I would suggest using something more intuitive.

Hope that helps.